# Smooth scrolling with scrollIntoView() only applies to a few first elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scroll

I'm working on a component used to display a reel of images obtained via websockets, because the number of images can be really high sometimes (say 400-500) I've written some logic inside the main parent component used to return a limited amount of images at one time (in this case its the currently selected image plus 5 images in each direction of the original object). All of this works fine but I've found that for some reason scrolling through the reel using the smooth behavior only works for the first 5 elements inside the reel - notice how this is the same number I'm using to pad the selected image in the optimization process.

**Parent component**

```
import RenderReelCard from '../../../components/cards/RenderReelCard/RenderReelCard';
import ChevronLeftSVG from '../../../assets/svg/ChevronLeftSVG';
import ChevronRightSVG from '../../../assets/svg/ChevronRightSVG';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { JobData, Task, TaskData } from '../../../components/types/misc';
import { processTasksToArray } from '../RenderInformation/RenderInformation.utils';
import Spinner from '../../../components/misc/Spinner/Spinner';
import { useStateMachine } from 'little-state-machine';
import { downloadFrame } from './RenderPreview.utils';
import { DateTime, Duration } from 'luxon';
import './styles.scss';

interface RenderPreviewProps {
    data?: JobData;
}

const RenderPreview = (props: RenderPreviewProps) => {

    const { data } = props;
    const [ imageData, setImageData ] = useState<TaskData>({});
    const [ currentID, setCurrentID ] = useState<string>();
    const [ firstTimeLoad, setFirstTimeLoad ] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const { state } = useStateMachine();

    const imageDataLength = Object.keys(data?.tasks?.finished || {})?.length;
    const finishedFrames = {...data?.tasks?.finished} as { [key: string]: Task };
    const jobID = data?.job_data?.id;
    const url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
    const previewSelectedImage = currentID ? `url("${url}/tether/view/${jobID}/output/thumbnails/${currentID?.padStart(4, '0')}_thumb.webp")` : '';

    const nextCard = () => {
        if(Number(currentID) >= (data?.job_data?.end || 0) || !currentID) return
        const currentIndex = Object.keys(finishedFrames).indexOf(currentID)
        const nextIndex = Object.keys(finishedFrames)[currentIndex + 1]
        if(currentIndex !== -1 && nextIndex){
           setCurrentID(nextIndex);
        }
    }

    const previousCard = () => {
        if(Number(currentID) <= 0 || !currentID) return
        const currentIndex = Object.keys(finishedFrames).indexOf(currentID)
        const previousIndex = Object.keys(finishedFrames)[currentIndex - 1]
        if(currentIndex !== -1 && previousIndex){
           setCurrentID(previousIndex);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = state?.jobOptions?.selectedFrameFromList;
        if(id){ setCurrentID(String(id)) }
    }, [state?.jobOptions?.selectedFrameFromList])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(data) {
            const processedIncomingData = processTasksToArray(data);
            setImageData(processedIncomingData);
            if(!firstTimeLoad && imageDataLength > 0){
                setFirstTimeLoad(true);
            }
        }
    }, [data])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(state?.jobOptions?.latestFrameMode && imageDataLength > 0) {
            setCurrentID(Object.keys(finishedFrames)[Object.keys(finishedFrames).length - 1]);
        }
    }, [imageDataLength])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!imageData || !finishedFrames) return
        setCurrentID(Object.keys(finishedFrames)[Object.keys(finishedFrames)?.length - 1]);
    }, [firstTimeLoad])

    return(
        <div className='renderPreview'>
            <div className='renderPeviewImage' 
                style={{
                    backgroundImage: imageDataLength > 0 ? previewSelectedImage : '',
                }} 
            >
                <div className='renderPreviewControlsContainer'>
                    <div className='renderPreviewControls'>
                        <button>Rerender</button>
                        <button>Stop</button>
                        <button onClick={() => downloadFrame(url, jobID || '', currentID || '')}>Download</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {currentID &&
                    <div className='onScreenMetricsContainer'>
                        <div className='metric'>
                            <span>Hostname</span>
                            <span>{finishedFrames[currentID]?.machine}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className='metric'>
                            <span>Date</span>
                            <span>{DateTime.fromMillis(data?.job_data?.submit_time || 0)?.toFormat('yyyy/MM/dd')}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className='metric'>
                            <span>Render time</span>
                            <span>{Duration.fromMillis(finishedFrames[currentID]?.time).toFormat("hh:mm:ss")}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                {imageDataLength === 0 && 
                    <Spinner text='Rendering first frame...'/>
                }
            </div>
            <div className='renderPreviewReel'>
                <div className='renderPreviewReelBg'
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: previewSelectedImage,
                    }} 
                >
                </div>
                <div className='renderPreviewFadeEffectLeft' 
                    onClick={previousCard}
                />
                <div className='renderPreviewFadeEffectRight' 
                    onClick={nextCard}
                />
                {currentID && 
                    <div className='renderPreviewReelCards'>
                        {Object.entries(finishedFrames).map(([key]) => (
                                (parseInt(key) >= parseInt(currentID) - 5) && 
                                (parseInt(key) <= parseInt(currentID) + 5) &&
                                <RenderReelCard
                                    key={`reelCard-${key}`}
                                    image={`${url}/tether/view/${jobID}/output/thumbnails/${String(key).padStart(4, '0')}_thumb.webp`} 
                                    index={parseInt(key)} 
                                    selected={key === currentID}
                                    currentlySelected={parseInt(currentID)}
                                />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                }
                <div className='renderPreviewReelControls'>
                        <button 
                            onClick={previousCard}
                        >
                            <ChevronLeftSVG fill='white'/>
                        </button>
                        <p>{currentID || 0} / {data?.job_data?.end || 0}</p>
                        <button 
                            onClick={nextCard}
                        >
                            <ChevronRightSVG fill='white'/>
                        </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RenderPreview;
```

**The image card component used inside parent component**

```
import { ComponentProps, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useWindowSize } from 'usehooks-ts';
import './styles.scss';

interface RenderReelCardProps extends ComponentProps<"div"> {
    index: number;
    image?: string;
    selected?: boolean;
    currentlySelected?: number;
}

const RenderReelCard = (props: RenderReelCardProps) => {

    const { index = 0, image, selected = false, currentlySelected = 0 } = props;
    const { width } = useWindowSize();
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const selectedClass = selected ? 'selected' : 'unSelected';

    const scrollToElement = () => {
        if(selected && ref.current) {
            ref.current.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                inline: 'center',
            })
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        scrollToElement();
    }, [width, selected]);

    return(
        <div 
            id={`renderPreviewReelCard-${index}`} 
            className=
            {`renderPreviewReelCard 
                ${selectedClass}
                ${index > currentlySelected && 'notSeen'}
            `}
            style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
            }} 
            data-key={props?.key}
            ref={ref}
            {...props}
        >
        </div>
    )

}

export default RenderReelCard;
```

I've written these in quite a rush so I apologize for any obvious mistakes or lack of linting, let me know if anyone has met this issue before or if there is any fix

Tried most about anything I can think of but can't quite figure it out